# Функция с уникальными данными для каждого обработчика.

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать обработчик, и чтобы там были функции со своими данными.
Делаю так:

```
console.log('refresh');
var ir = 0;
var f = function() {
    ir++;
    console.log('Кнопка добавить TAP ' + ir);
    return function() {
        console.log('TAP-' + ir);
    };
};
for (var i = 0; i < thiss.getStore().getCount(); i++) {
    Ext.EventManager.on('friends-btn-delete-' + (i+1), 'tap', f());//Добавляем событие
}
```

Ну и вот результат нажатия и на первую кнопку и на вторую:

```
TAP-2   --- Первая кнопка
TAP-2   --- Вторая кнопка
```

В чем проблема, не могу понять. Помогите, пожалуйста сделать так, чтобы в результатах было:

```
TAP-1
TAP-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так - будет работать:

```
var f = function() {
    var i = ir++;
    console.log('Кнопка добавить TAP ' + i);
    return function() {
        console.log('TAP-' + i);
    };
};
```

Comment: Ага, верно. А можете объяснить, почему так происходит?

Comment: ir - условно глобальна, следовательно нужно сохранять копию её значения